# Select multiple entries from table with where clause of nvarchar column

Tags: sql

I have a table that has a `nvarchar` column; I need to search multiple entries with that as `where` clause.

I'm able to search for one entity one time like when checknumber is 1906572, but I need to retrieve data for multiple entities '**like**' checknumber (`nvarchar`) is in either of these all: 663096, 663105, 663107, 663109, 663110 because one by one search is very time consuming.

When m searching below:
Select invoice, voucher, date from bankdetails where checknumber like N'%654217' m getting result but when m putting where checknumber = N'654217' or where checknumber = '654217' m not getting any output.

And I cant export data one by one I have around 2000 checknumber.

Please note that datatype is `NVARCHAR`, where entity in (' ', ' ') will not work with `Nvarchar`, don't post answers without testing, thank you

Comment: post your current query.

Comment: ...and DDL. And read & act on [mcve].

Comment: When datatype is NVARCHAR, where entity in ('663096', '663105') will not work with Nvarchar - what do you mean by `will not work` - it throws an error for you or what?

Answer (score 2):

in you sql `where` clause instead of using `entity = 1906572` use `entity in (663096, 663105, 663107, 663109, 663110)`

Answer (score 1):

Be careful not to mix data types.  So, be sure to include single quotes because the comparison values should be strings:

```
checknumber = '1906572' 
checknumber in ('663096', '663105', '663107', '663109', '663110')
```

Mixing data types makes it harder for the optimizer to choose the best execution plan.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select * 
from [TableName] 
where checknumber in ('663096', '663105', '663107', '663109', '663110')
```